# Is it required to mark class as final to make it immutable?

Tags: java

The concept of immutability in java says's that class needs to be marked final to make it immutable. 
My question is if we do not mark a class as final then it can be subclassed but still it will be the object of sub-class that will be mutable and not the base class. The state/properties of base class will remain immutable as we will mark properties of the base class as private.

Second question is are immutable class and immutable objects two different concepts in java?

Comment: Consider what happens when the sub-class overrides an accessor method of the base class. While the base fields are still immutable, every observer will see the state changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we do not mark a class as final then it can be subclassed but still it will be the object of sub-class that will be mutable and not the base class. The state/properties of base class will remain immutable as we will mark properties of the base class as private.

Suppose we have a class `C1` that has only `final` fields but is not itself declared as `final`.

When the someone creates a class `C2` as a subclass of `C1`, they can include mutable fields in `C2`.  Since instances of `C2` are also instances of `C1`, we now have the situation that some instances of `C1` *may be changed*.  Therefore, we cannot consider `C1` to be an immutable class.

> Are immutable class and immutable objects two different concepts in java?

Yea.  Kind of.  It depends on who you talk to:

- Some people would argue that an immutable object is any object that is an instance of an immutable class.
- Other people would argue that an immutable object is any object that cannot be changed after it is constructed.  For example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html).  And that would (by some stretch) include objects that cannot change purely for reasons of API (i.e. method) semantics.

I would avoid using the term "immutable objects" without clarifying which of those two definitions apply.

To illustrate the ambiguity, an instance created using `new C1()` could be viewed as an immutable object (since it cannot be changed) or not (since it is not an instance of an immutable class).

Comment: "The concept of immutability in java says's that class needs to be marked final to make it immutable. My question is if we do not mark a class as final then it can be subclassed but still it will be the object of sub-class that will be mutable and not the base class. The state/properties of base class will remain immutable as we will mark properties of the base class as private". Can some one please answer this?

Comment: 1)  Technically, it is a statement, not a question.  2) I did address it.  What didn't you understand about my answer?